# append computer name to url

Tags: vbscript, scripting

We currently use vbscript to append each users machine name to a URL provided by the host.

```
Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network") 
document.write(" <META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT=""0;URL=http://as400.tl.ccbg.com/jha/startslakeMOU.html?" + objNetwork.ComputerName + """>")
```

VBScript no longer works in IE11 and we need a new way to accomplish this. Is there a better way to do this and what are our options?

Answer (score 0):

If you add the following to your HEAD tag, your VBScript will run:

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=10">
```

[EDITED]

Take a look at [META Tags and Locking in Future Compatibility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/cc817574.aspx) to understand how to activate the different compatibility Modes.

Comment: Is there a more long term solution, like using another scripting language to accomplish this?

Comment: Sure, you can use java script anytime

Comment: Why will it run? How about you expand the answer so others have a better explanation of the problem instead of just doing the bare minimum.

Comment: Thanks, our guy doesn't know java script. any examples?